# Bring background-image to frontground. Possible or not?

Tags: html, css, background, position, background-image

I really need to get the background picture in front of another picture and I can't find a way to do it without using absolute positioning.

```
<div><?php get_avatar($x, 56); ?></div>
```

get_avatar displays an image.
So the HTML looks like:

```
<div><img src="whatever"></div>
```

A little help anyone?

Comment: no-one is going to be able to give you any kind of useful answer with that little to go on. The PHP code does nothing to help us answer the question. Show us the finished HTML code, or at least give us a clue as to what the `get_avatar()` function's output looks like.

Comment: You you want a CSS `background-image` to be displayed in front of the `whatever` image from the `<img>` tag, is that right? So where is the background image? is it on the `<div>` or the `<img>` tag? You're still not showing us enough detail.

Comment: The background-image is on the <div> . I didn't know i can pun background-image on an <img>

Comment: you *can* put a background image on an `<img>`, but obviously it would be fairly pointless unless the foreground image has transparent bits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use css `multiple background` property

check this 
http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

or

Edit:

you can give your another pic z-index in minus like this:

```
    div{
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
}
img{
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1
}

<div>
 <img alt="" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/45454&text=images">
</div>
```

check the example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/5vpG7/

Comment: I forgot to mention, I need to get this to work on IE unfortunately, so i can't use CSS3. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `z-index`? seriously? why not just set it to `visibility:hidden;`?

Comment: @spudley; suppose if the background-image is transparent.

Comment: well, he didn't specify that (but then, there was a *lot* of relevant info he didn't specify without getting a lot of prompting)

Comment: yup :) that's why i am going through his question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css z-index property.

Set z-index:999;

Answer (score 0):

Your code (with a background image style added for clarity):

```
<div style='background-image:url(something.jpg);'><img src="whatever.jpg"></div>
```

In order to make the background image show instead of the foreground image, the easiest solution is simply to make the `<img>` invisible.

Two ways to do this using CSS:

1. Set it to `visibility:hidden;`
2. Set it to `opacity:1;`

The first solution is the best, as it will work in all browsers.

Changing the opacity via Javascript would have the benefit of allowing you to do a fade effect, but expect problems with IE if you do that.

Hope that helps.